# UIPickerView taking values of another UIPickerView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uipickerview

I have a problem with multiple UIPickerView, I have 8 of them on UICollectionView and when Im scrolling the first PickerView and the fifth PickerView starts scrolling by itself and takes the same value of the first one, then I scroll the second PickerView and takes the same value of the sixth PickerView and so on. There's a solution of this problem? Thanks guys.

Here's a video of the this problem: [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lhnmMPntIUo)

Code:

```
import UIKit

class Cards: UICollectionViewCell {
    var number: [String] = []
    let firaSansFont = FiraSansFont()

    let cardView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
        view.layer.cornerRadius = 14
        view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.20
        view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 10)
        view.layer.shadowRadius = 10
        view.frame.size = CGSize(width: 200, height: 200)
        return view
    }()

    let productoTitle: UILabel = {
        let attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey:Any] = [.foregroundColor : #colorLiteral(red: 0.2901960784, green: 0.2901960784, blue: 0.2901960784, alpha: 1)]
        let label = UILabel()
        label.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: "Titulo", attributes: attributes)
        label.frame = CGRect(x: 16, y: 16, width: 200, height: 30)
        label.textAlignment = .left
        return label
    }()

    let backgroundCard: UIImageView = {
        let image = UIImageView(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "tortillaNormal"))
        image.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        image.layer.opacity = 0.5
        image.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 20, width: 160, height: 160)
        return image
    }()

    let numberPicker: UIPickerView = {
        let picker = UIPickerView()
        picker.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 70, width: 160, height: 100)
        return picker
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
        layer.cornerRadius = 14
        layer.shadowOpacity = 0.20
        layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 10)
        layer.shadowRadius = 10
        addViews()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func addViews() {
        for i in 0...100 { number.append(String(i)) }
        addSubview(cardView)
        addSubview(backgroundCard)
        productoTitle.font = firaSansFont.regular(size: 28)
        addSubview(productoTitle)
        numberPicker.dataSource = self
        numberPicker.delegate = self
        addSubview(numberPicker)
        let cantidadLabel: UILabel = {
            let label = UILabel()
            label.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 70, width: 200, height: 20)
            label.text = "Cantidad"
            label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16, weight: .semibold)
            label.textAlignment = .center
            return label
        }()
        addSubview(cantidadLabel)
    }
}

extension Cards: UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return 100
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {
        var pickerLabel: UILabel? = (view as? UILabel)
        if pickerLabel == nil {
            pickerLabel = UILabel()
            pickerLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 30, weight: .bold)
            pickerLabel?.textAlignment = .center
        }
        pickerLabel?.text = number[row]

        return pickerLabel!
    }
}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource,          UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 8
  }

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = cardCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellID, for: indexPath) as! Cards
    cell.productoTitle.text = productosTitles[indexPath.item]
    cell.backgroundCard.image = productosImages[indexPath.item]
    return cell
  }
}
```

Comment: Try to reduce the problem to only 2 or 3 UIPickerViews. Try to identify thre issue with the reduced poblem and then extend the tsk.
For reduced problems it's most often easier to find the bug. stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: It looks like this is a cell reuse issue. You may want to look at the logic for creating your Cards in the UICollectionViewCellData source and post that code here for some additional assistance.

Comment: @Steve I already posted the code, thank you.

Comment: @milbrandt when I use 4 UIPickerViews works fine, but when I put 5 or 6 the problem starts showing.

Comment: Looking at the code it looks like the cell reuse is causing the problem you may want to look into the prepareforreuse method on the cell to recreate the picker. Sorry I’m not at a computer right now to be more specific but it may be a good place to start.

Comment: @Steve thank you, now it works with prepareForReuse method.

Comment: No problem. Glad it helped. Mind if I write it as an answer so you can make it the accepted answer ?

Answer (score 0):

This issue happends because Your cells are reused. There are few possibilities to solve issue:

1. Do not reuse cells. This way is bad for performance.
2. Implement prepareForReuse(). In this method You need to discard all animations and clear cell.